# Sheets in LibreOffice Writer (similar to that in Calc)?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am writing a document on a subject, but with many sub-topics.

I want to have each sub-topic in it's own individual sheet like you have in LibreOffice Calc, but I have not figured out a way to do this. Does anyone know?

It could be an alternative to have some sort of index, but I do not know how to make that (I tried, it was too complicated). Preferably tabs or sheets through native program features (so that it can be opened and read by others too).

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I haven't explored doing this in LO, but I've had a similar need to pull together sub-topics like you describe.  I found a number of note takers useful for this: [BasKet](http://basket.kde.org/screenshots.php), [KeepNote](http://keepnote.org/index.shtml#about), and [Zim](http://zim-wiki.org/), all free, each with a slightly different approach, and you can export into a "master" document.  There's also a relatively inexpensive commercial tool (with free trial), [Scrivener](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php), used by professional writers to organize complex documents.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions, but I am afraid it is not what I am looking for (as I want something that I can send to others without them needing to install new software or extensions). But it could be useful for other people, and me too in other situations. So thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to organize and access content in Writer:

- Master Documents;
- Simple odt files, accessing sub-topics using the Navigator window;
- If you really need Sheets: Create a Calc file, and embed Writer OLE objects on different sheets (i wouldn't recommend this, since it makes simple tasks like formatting pages very difficult.

I recommend using a simple plain odt Writer file and use the Navigator, maybe in connection with setting bookmarks. The Navigator (Menu View -> Navigator or <kbd>F5</kbd>) can list the heading structure, sections, bookmarks and so on.